# Refer to the same cell always, no matter the value

Tags: excel, reference, cell, absolute

I have a sheet with an Auto Refresh Execution log in it. This tab updates every 4 hours and gives a date and time for when the data was last pulled from Salesforce.
The most recent refresh is always the top. So cell A2 will always show the last time the data was refreshed.
On an overview page, I want to refer to this cell to show there when the data was last pulled from Salesforce. However, since the Auto Refresh Execution log updates every 4 hours and there is a new entry in cell A2, I am struggling a bit to refer to that cell.

I have referenced it this way:

**='Auto Refresh Execution Log'!A2** -> But after 4 hours this shows the old entry from 4 hours ago. By then then the cell in the formula becomes ='Auto Refresh Execution Log'!**A3** because the entry is old and moved down to A3

I have also tried:

**='Auto Refresh Execution Log'!A$2** -> But this shows #REF! error once the execution log updates and throws in a new entry in A2.

I also tried:

**='Auto Refresh Execution Log'!$$A$2** -> But this also shows the old entry from 4 hours (or more) ago. By then the cell in the formula becomes ='Auto Refresh Execution Log'!**A3** because the entry is old and moved down a row or a few rows.

Basically I always want to reference to the value in A2, no matter what the value in A2 is every time the log updates. I guess the issue is, that technically there is always a row added, which is why I don't know how to do this. Can somebody help?

Comment: Give this a go =INDIRECT("A2")

Comment: I tried =INDIRECT('Auto Refresh Execution Log'!A2) but it shows an error

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The error is #REF!

Comment: better use it as W_O_L_F has suggested
if sheetname is needed then try googling for "INDIRECT Function Excel: Get values from different sheet"

Comment: Yeah I found nothing useful at all..

Comment: =INDIRECT("Sheet1!A1") works for me